# Proving every element of $\mathbb{F}[x]/(p(x))$ can be expressed uniquely

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Proving every element of $\mathbb{F}[x]/(p(x))$ can be expressed uniquely in the form $a(x) + (p(x))$ where $\text{deg}(a) < \text{deg}(p)$

this is a homework problem and I'm stuck, here is my attempt:

Let $b(x) + (p(x)) \in \mathbb{F}[x]/(p(x))$

If $\text{deg}(b) < \text{deg}(p)$ I am done, else $\text{deg}(b) \geq \text{deg}(p)$. I then divide $b$ by $p$:

$\implies b(x) = a(x) + q(x)p(x)$ where $\text{deg}(a) < \text{deg}(p)$

$\implies b(x) - a(x) \in (p(x)) \iff b(x) + (p(x)) = a(x) + (p(x))$ by the rule of equality for cosets, this proves this existence.

Now I must show it is unique,

Assume $a(x) + (p(x)) = a_1(x) + (p(x))$ with $\text{deg}(a),\text{deg}(a_1) < \text{deg}(p)$ Then

$a(x) - a_1(x) = q(x)p(x)$ for some $q(x)$ Now I am struggling to find a contradiction.

I tried to say, if $q(x) \not=0$ then tried to work with the degree, but I cannot find a contradiction.

many thanks

Comment: What’s the degree of $a(x) - a_1(x)$, what’s the degree of $q(x)·p(x)$? Put differently: Can you bound the former from above, the latter from below?

Comment: @k.stm The degree of $p(x)q(x)$ is the degree of $p$ + the degree of $q$, I am not sure about the degree of $a-a_1$

Comment: Suposse $deg(a)\geq deg(a_1)$ than the degree of $a-a_1$ is less or equal the degree of $a$ which is less than degree of $p$.

Comment: @DH. Well, maybe you can say at least *something* about the degree of $a - a_1$, even if you can’t *know* the degree of $a + b$ for polynomials $a$ and $b$ for sure if you only know their degrees. (You can’t know it because, after all, if $a = X^n + X^{n-1} + … + 1$ and $b = - (X^n + X^{n-1} + … + X^{k+1})$ for some $k ∈ \{0,…,n\}$, then $a + b = X^k + X^{k-1} + … + 1$ has degree $k$ which could be anything. Well, of course anything between $0$ and $n$ …)

Comment: Most proofs of the division algorithm include a proof of the *uniqueness* of the remainder. That's exactly what you need.

Comment: @k.stm I made some progress, would this be correct? If $q(x) \not = 0 $ $\text{deg}(a-a_1) \geq \text{deg}(p)$ which is a contradiction since $\text{deg}(a-a_1) \leq \text{max} (\text{deg}(a),\text{deg}(a_1)) < \text{deg}(p)$?

Comment: @DH. Yes, seems legit.

Comment: @k.stm cool, thanks for your help and everyone else who commented. Do I delete the thread now there is no answer?

Comment: @DH. Best practice: Answer it yourself, elaborating a bit, accept your own answer. Else, I’d just leave it.

Answer (score 1):

solved by noticing if $q(x) \not= 0$ then $\text{deg}(a-a_1) \geq \text{deg}(p)$ but this is a contradiction since $\text{deg}(a-a_1) \leq \text{max}(\text{deg}(a),\text{deg}(a_1)) < \text{deg}(p)$ hence $q = 0$ and $ a = a_1$